# Laravel CSRF token for AJAX CORS

Tags: ajax, laravel, cors, csrf

How can I supply a csrf token for cross domain(subdomain) request in Laravel.

Both of the domain `domain.tld` and `sub.domain.tld` is run under the same Laravel Framework,

therefore I could use `csrf_token()` in the `sub.domain.tld`, I directly attach it to the request but it keep giving me tokenMismatchException, and I tried to turn off the csrf filter and dump the `Input::('_token')` and the `Session::token()`, it always **DOES NOT MATCH**

So, how can I supply a token for for another domain?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the correct headers to allow ajax requests cross domain/subdomain?

If not, in `app/filters.php` in your `App::before` filter, add:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $host = explode( '.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
    $subdomain = array_shift( $host );
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://' . $subdomain . '.yourdomain.com');
});
```